# Do I face any issue with different PNR but same airlines & same airport at Kuwait, although I can still get a VOA as a GCC resident?

Tags: air-travel, transit, international-travel, airport-transfer, kuwait

I am flying with two different PNR with the same airline, Saudia, from Jeddah to Kuwait via Riyadh, and Kuwait to Kuala Lumpur. I have no check-in bags. Please advise.